# MS Excel 2013 - crash after editing cell value

Tags: vba, excel, macros, ms-office

I am currently facing a very anoying issue with my Excel workbook, and I would like to ask you for help.

My workbook works as a quotation tool and generates a PDF afterwards.

First, you need to enter data from different sources (for e.g. PDFs, Excel Workbooks, etc.) to a Worksheet called Master. You can do some calculation with simple formulas and can export the results into another sheet called Calc_Overview. In this process, the data is also formatted to the right font, color and size.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    For i = 12 To .UsedRange.rows.Count
       If .Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
           .Cells(i, 2).Copy Destination:=Target.Cells(k, 4)
           .Range(.Cells(i, 4), .Cells(i, 5)).Copy _
             Target.Range("F" + k, "G" + k).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

           .Range(.Cells(i, 6), .Cells(i, 7)).Copy _
             Destination:=Target.Range("I" + k, "J" + k)

           .Cells(i, 8).Copy _
             Destination:=Target.Cells(k, 8)
           k = k + 1               
      End If
    Next i
End With
```

After this operation, the user can see a summary of his entered and calculated data. With another macro, which copies the rows into 3 different worksheets (depending on the kind), the calculation process is finished.

This is my copy function :

```
    Function CopyTable(Typ As String, Counter As Integer, Count As Integer) As Integer

    With Worksheets("Calc_Overview")
        .Range("A" & Count & ":" & "D" & Count).Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets(Typ).Range("A" & 5 + Counter)

        .Range("G" & Count & ":" & "H" & Count).Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets(Typ).Range("E" & 5 + Counter)
    End With

    CopyTable = Counter + 1

   End Function
```

**Now my problem:**
If you try to edit the data which was transfered into the final worksheet, it often happens that Excel crashes without any reason. After editing a cell value,pressing enter or clicking another cell will let Excel crash.

I already turned off the 'Automatically Flash Fill' and 'Show Quick Analysis' option, but the problem still occurs..

Has anyone a clue what might cause this problem? I already replaced the final worksheets by new ones without copying anything from the 'broken' ones - also without any success. I am using a Windows 10 PC (x64) with an 32-Bit Microsoft Office 2013.

I am really looking fowards to any tips or solutions regarding this problem!

Many thanks

Moritz

Comment: `Cells(CStr(i), ...)` why this conversion of i to string? vba will do the conversion to str then back to integer. BTW This makes your code a bit noisy for someone trying to help.

Comment: Do you have a `Worksheet_Change` or `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event in your vba-project? These are running if you change a cell value or if you press enter after a cell was selected. If yes, you might look into these to find the issue (just a guess)

Comment: @A.S.H Thank you for this advice, i have changed this!

Comment: @Lukas: I already checked this, unfortunately the workbook does not use the Change or SelectionChange event at any time..

Comment: What happens if you change all the copying operations to values only? and better without using copy/paste, but by direct assignment `targetRange.Value = srcRange.Value2`

Comment: @A.S.H I changed the copy sub, but without any difference. As the macro is working without any problems, I believe the workbook might be broken at all.. Moreover the problem only occurs from time to time, it cannot be reproduced clearly..

Answer (score 0):

I have an update for you:

- changing the copy method does not change anything - the problem still occurs.
- [This is how is looks after you edit the cell - the cell expands and excel is freezing without any reason with a very high cpu load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSk70.png)